# Copy a Worksheet if the Cell Value equals a certain string using row and column indexes

Tags: excel, vba

The purpose of this is to find the column who has the header "Type Test" and loop through that column, in this case B to find all unique value cells. If the string in column B is unique and does not replace, I need it to make a copy of the worksheet whose name matches the trial name in column A. So for Test 1 who has a row index of 3 and a column index of 2, will make a copy of the worksheet in the current workbook called "DEF" and rename the copy to be "Test 1"

For example here is my data

1. ```
    A            B
   ```
2. ```
    Trial     Type_Test
   ```
3. ```
    DEF        Test 1
   ```
4. ```
    ABC        Test 3
   ```
5. ```
    ABC        Test 10
   ```
6. ```
    DEF        Test 14
   ```
7. ```
    ABC        Test 10
   ```

However, I dont want to make a copy of the sheet ABC if the column B values repeat for column A, so since rows 3 and 5 are the same, I only want to make copies of ABC sheet twice, once for row 2 and once for row 3. Row 5 can be ignored since it is the same as row 3.

I have written a code that does the first part regarding make a sheet and renaming it, I just cant get the copy the other worksheet part.

```vb
Public Sub Main()

Dim srtsht As Variant, sysnum As Variant, arr As Variant, partnum As Variant
Dim wsh As Worksheet

    srtsht = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E15")

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") ' store data in array where each item is associated with a unique key
        For Each sysnum In srtsht
            arr = .Item(sysnum)
        Next sysnum
    For Each value In .Keys
        On Error Resume Next
        If value <> "" Then
            Set wsh = Nothing ' clear the variable wsh
            Set wsh = Worksheets(CStr(value)) ' try to set wsh to the sheet with Value as name
            On Error GoTo 0
            If wsh Is Nothing Then 

            Call position 
         
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(A_row,A_col).Value = "ABC" Then 
            Worksheets("ABC").Copy After:=ActiveSheet 
            wsh = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(A_row,A_col).Values 
            Worksheets("ABC (2)").name = wsh 
            wsh.name = CStr(Value)
            End If 
            Else 
               MsgBox "Sheet" & Values & "already exists.", vbInformation 
            End If 
          End If  
       Next Value 
     End With 
End Sub 

Sub position () 
Dim syswaivernum As Range, partnumber As Range

For Each syswaivernum In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z20")
        If syswaivernum.value = "Number(s)" Then
        sysnumcol = syswaivernum.Column
        sysnumrow = syswaivernum.Row
        End If
    Next syswaivernum
For Each partnumber In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z20")
        If partnumber.value = "Part" Then
        A_col = partnumber.Column
        A_row = partnumber.Row
    End If
Next partnumber

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your question is related to your title. One can use `Cell` with row and column indexes. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Sorceri I have added the code I have written thus far. I am able to make new sheets named Test 1 Test 2 and so on, but I cannot make copies of the ABC, etc. sheets

Comment: @BigBen I have tried doing If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(A_row,A_column).Value = "ABC" Then Worksheets("ABC").Copy After:= ActiveSheet, but it does not work

Comment: How did you assign values to `A_row` and `A_column`? Please create a [reprex].

Comment: You create a dictionary and then immediately call `arr = .Item(sysnum)`  - your dictionary has no content though ?  Aren't you going to put any content in it?

Comment: Your description doesn't match your posted data - Col B vs E from the description...  Seems like your code is from https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-vba-save-key-list-values-to-a-variable-that/7bb85dc4-7272-4a77-b816-c489e78d997d  Always helps to let us know it's from elsewhere, otherwise we're left wondering why you wrote it like that.

Comment: @BigBen I have just posted my entire code with the sub that explains A_row and A_col

Comment: @TimWilliams when I run through the beginning of the code, it shows that the values in column E are stored in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - see comments inline:

```vb
Public Sub Main()

    Dim wb As Workbook, tst As String, wsName As String
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, dict As Object
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ws.Range("E2:E15").Cells
        tst = c.Value
        If Not dict.exists(tst) Then 'first time seeing this value?
            dict.Add tst, True '###
            If Not SheetExists(tst) Then
                wsName = c.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value    'sheet to be copied
                If SheetExists(wsName) Then 'if there's a sheet for wsName
                    wb.Worksheets(wsName).Copy After:=ws       'copy the sheet
                    wb.Worksheets(ws.Index + 1).Name = tst  '### rename the copy
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Sheet '" & wsName & "' already exists"
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

'Does a sheet named `SheetName` exist?
'  Defaults to checking `ThisWorkbook` if `wb` is not specified
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, _
                     Optional wb As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I tried the code you provided, however I am getting an error saying object variable or with block variable not set at line                                                                           "If  Not dict.exists(tst) Then" When I step through the code, it holds my value in tst but then cannot identify wsName

Comment: Tested and added a couple of fixes (flagged with ###)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either; I am still getting the same error in the same line as before. When you say wsName = c.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value, what does the "A" refer too? The range is stated above to be "E2:E15" would that have anything effect on the code not running?

Comment: You will need to adjust those ranges to suit your data.  Col E is "Type_Test" in your posted data sample and ColA is "Trial"

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I got confused when I added example data in the posting. Even after I have adjusted the ranges to fit my data it does not solve the object variable or with block error. Every variable has been defined and all if statements have their end if statements

Comment: Did you make changes to my posted code (other than adjusting ranges)?

Comment: I tried replacing the If Nots with just If statements. I am not sure what If Not means. I may be misreading the code, but arent both statements calling for new sheets to be made?

Comment: I did try adding an Else statement in the first If Not statement, but that cannot run since the If Not line is where the error is being thrown.

Comment: `If Not dict.exists(tst)` = "if the key 'tst' doesn't already exist in dict" ie. it's testing to see if we've seen the value of `tst` before.  It might be worth investing some time in a couple of VBA tutorials, or read the online help if you're not sure about what (eg) `Not` means.

Comment: I guess I am used to checking by saying if the key does already exist skip else do this.

Comment: Correction, I have managed to get by the initial error, now I am running into a problem with wb in function SheetExists. Since it was defined as a global variable, i wrote dim wb as workbook in the function and then set it to be thisworkbook, however now I am being told Subscript out of range.

Comment: If you only care about  the workbook where the code is running then you can just write `SheetExists = Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing`

Comment: I was able to figure out my problem with the subscript out of range issue. Now I am wondering if there is a way to write if there is no sheet titled what is in column "A" then skip to the next value in column "B". The function SheetExists checks to see if a sheet with the name in column "A" exists, so would I be able to add a line after that to say it does not and to skip to the next value in the column?

Comment: See edits above

Comment: While waiting for your response, I actually tried adding an If-Statement after the tst = c.value saying "If IsEmpty(c) Then GoTo Skip End If" and wrote skip to appear right before the Next c line. Do you think that method is sufficient and has proper code architecture?

Comment: Typically I would only use Goto for error handling or maybe as a way to break out from inside nested loops.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your suggestion. I will try with your edits instead.

Comment: Can you explain what `SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing` please? I am getting confused with the double negatives.

Comment: Also is there a way to adjust the Function and set wb to equal a closed workbook? I want to search a closed workbook to see if there is any worksheet with the SheetName value and if not make a copy of the sheet and paste it into the active workbook

Comment: `SheetExists` is True if `wb.Sheets(SheetName)` is an actual object (ie. a sheet that exists).  If it's not an existing sheet then that line throws an error, and the function defaults to returning False.   You cannot set wb to a closed workbook - you will need to open it first.

Comment: I have updated my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961329/search-through-closed-workbook-for-worksheets-with-specific-name-then-make-copie where i am able to open the closed workbook, but when I try to then copy the worksheets in the closed workbook nothing happens.