# Search through closed workbook for worksheets with specific name then make copies of that sheet into active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that currently opens the closed workbook titled `"Specification and Configuration Document.xlsx"`, now I need it to look for any sheets within this closed workbook that have the value wsName which changes as the for loop progresses. The main part of this code operates in the active workbook titled `"SD093_W.xlsm"`, sysnum variable is produced as the code loops through column E searching for unique values. If a unique value is found then it looks at Column D cell in the same row as Column E and reads the value then assigned to variable wsName.

Once the wsName value has been determined, I need the code to look in the closed workbook `"Specification and Configuration Document.xlsx"`and make a copy of the wsName. For example say the wsName found in the active Workbook is `Test2` then I want to go into the closed workbook, search for the worksheet titled `Test2`, make a copy of it, and then paste it into the active workbook and rename it the value of sysnum.

This is what I have so far for my code: Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Global sysrow As Integer, sysnum As String, wsName As String

 Public Sub Main()
 Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Range, dict As Object ', wsName As String

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
 For Each i In ws.Range("E2:E15").Cells ' i = every WD number
     sysnum = i.value
     sysrow = i.Row
     syscol = i.Column
    If sysnum = "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
    End If
If Not dict.Exists(sysnum) Then ' check if unique value already exists before adding it to dictionary
    dict.Add sysnum, True
    If Not SheetExists(sysnum) Then
        wsName = i.EntireRow.Columns("D").value ' sheet to be copied
        If SheetExists(wsName) Then ' if there is a sheet for wsName to copy
          wb.Worksheets(wsName).Copy After:=ws ' copy the sheet
            wb.Worksheets(ws.Index + 1).name = sysnum ' rename the copy
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet " & sysnum & " already exists"
    End If
End If

specmin = Application.Match("SPEC min", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("A2:Q2"), 0) ' column index for SPEC min in SD tab
    IsError (specmin)
specmax = Application.Match("SPEC max", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("A2:Q2"), 0) ' column index for SPEC max in SD tab
    IsError (specmax)
formula = Application.Match("Formula / step size", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("A2:Q2"), 0)
    IsError (formula)

 Next i
 End Sub
```

---

```
 ' check does a sheet named wsName exist in default current Workbook
 Function SheetExists(SheetName As String)
   Dim wb As Workbook, filepath As String
   filepath = "Specification and Configuration Document.xlsx"
   If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=filepath) 'ThisWorkbook
   On Error Resume Next
   SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
 End Function
```

Comment: Your SheetExists function will not work as you expect and may end up checking the wrong workbook.  *Every time you call it* `If wb Is Nothing` will be true (since you did nothing to populate it before testing for Nothing) so it will always run the `Workbooks.Open` step.   If that workbook is already open (eg. from a previous call to that function) then Excel assigns the *last-opened* workbook to `wb` (whic hmay not be the workbook you wanted).

Comment: ...if you know you need to work with that file you should open it in your main code, and then pass it to `SheetExists` as a second argument.

Comment: You can't easily debug that code with that `On Error Resume Next` in `Main` though.

Comment: You're checking both `SheetExists(sysnum)` *and* `SheetExists(wsName)` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams So I should have filepath be defined in the `Main` and then have it be opened in `SheetExists`

Comment: @TimWilliams I am looking for `SheetExists(wsName) in the closed workbook that I am trying to define the file for

Comment: I understand the check for `wsName`, but what about your line `If Not SheetExists(sysnum) Then` though?

Comment: @TimWilliams Oh I thought you were looking at the function. The `If Not SheetExists(sysnum)` line says if there is no worksheet in the active workbook with the name (sysnum value) then it will ask to make a copy but in order to make a copy it has to be able to go into the closed workbook to find the sheet that can be copied

Comment: But the sheet to be copied is name wsName, not sysnum?

Comment: Correct, in the closed workbook, it has worksheets that are named the values that are looped through in wsName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from comment above:

```vb
Dim sysrow As Long, syscol As Long, sysnum As String, wsName As String

Public Sub Main()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Range, dict As Object ', wsName As String
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'pass the full path and filename, or (eg) use `Thisworkbook.Path`
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Specification and Configuration Document.xlsx")
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each i In ws.Range("E2:E15").Cells ' i = every WD number
        sysnum = i.Value
        sysrow = i.Row
        syscol = i.Column
        If Len(sysnum) > 0 Then
            If Not dict.Exists(sysnum) Then
                dict.Add sysnum, True
                If Not SheetExists(sysnum, wb) Then
                    wsName = i.EntireRow.Columns("D").Value ' sheet to be copied
                    If SheetExists(wsName, wbSrc) Then ' if there is a sheet for wsName to copy
                        wbSrc.Worksheets(wsName).Copy After:=ws ' copy the sheet
                        wb.Worksheets(ws.Index + 1).Name = sysnum ' rename the copy
                    End If 'wsName sheet exists
                Else
                    MsgBox "Sheet " & sysnum & " already exists"
                End If   'sysnum sheet exists
            End If       'new sysnum value
            '....
        End If 'sysnum not zero-length
    
    Next i
End Sub

'Does a sheet named `wsName` exist in Workbook `wb` ?
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, wb As Workbook)
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Using this, I get an error saying "Argument not optional" on line `If Not SheetExists(sysnum) Then` do I need to add another argument after sysnum to match the function?

Comment: You would use `ThisWorkbook` or `wbSrc`, depending on which workbook you want to check in.

Comment: Is there a way to `set wbSrc` to be a filepath without having it open. Right now the command opens the file, but I just want it to look in the file without it being open so that the sheets can be copied into `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: "I just want it to look in the file without it being open" - you can't do that though.

Comment: Oh, ok then. I have successfully made a copy of the sheet from `wbSrc` to `ThisWorkbook` but now it is throwing an error at `specmin = Application.Match("SPEC min", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("A2:Q2"), 0)` saying subscript out of range. I believe that is occurring because the copy of the sheet is not being renamed using line `wbSrc.Worksheets(ws.Index + 1).name = sysnum` but it is not throwing an error there so i am not sure

Comment: I can't understand why you keep switching between `sysnum` and `wsName` for the worksheet name...

Comment: `If SheetExists(wsName, wbSrc) Then
                wbSrc.Worksheets(wsName).Copy After:=ws ' copy the sheet
                wbSrc.Worksheets(wsName).name = sysnum` in this code it is searching the closed workbook that is set to the filepath `wbSrc` for worksheets within the workbook named `wsName` once it finds the sheet, it makes a copy into the active workbook that is being used and I want it to then rename the copy to be `sysnum`

Comment: OK my bad - I see that now

Comment: Thats ok, I know I am not the best at explaining and it can be confusing. Do you know why it is saying subscript out of range now that you see my naming convention

Comment: `wbSrc.Worksheets(wsName).name = sysnum` should be `wb.Worksheets(wsName).name = sysnum`

Comment: Edited my answer above to add the full code

Comment: For Function `SheetExists` why will the code not run without the line `On Error Resume Next`? I do not want the code to ignore potential errors. Could I say `On Error GoTo Message` and have a message after the line `SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing` saying `Message: MsgBox = "Unknown Error"`

Comment: `SheetExists` only returns True or False - if it returns False then you handle that in the calling code...  There's no need to raise and handle an "expected" error (one which you know the cause of, and have anticipated may occur)

Comment: Ok, for some reason I am getting a subscript out of range error message, but all my function says is `On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: Maybe you have "Break on all errors" checked in your VB options ?  "Break in class module" is probably more useful.

Comment: Oh I did have break on all errors checked. Can you explain why "break on all errors" caused the error, but "break in class module" does not?

Comment: "Break on all errors" breaks even when there's an error handler: the other options only break when there's no active error handler.

Comment: Ok so between "break in class module" or "break on unhandled errors" which would you suggest is better to have for error trapping

Comment: I use break in class module

Comment: Ok is there a major difference between the two?

Comment: That's something you can research online?  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BreakInClassModule.aspx#:~:text=The%20Break%20In%20Class%20Module%20is%20the%20most%20important%20because,accessible%20on%20the%20Tools%20menu.

Comment: Does it matter that my macro is saved as a `Module` and not as a `Class Module`

Comment: It just makes sure if you *are* working with objects then you get to see the error inside an object.  Works as expected with regular modules.